# What is that Google web site management tool called?

Tags: google

A year (or maybe 2) ago, Google announced they were working on releasing a management tool for static HTML sites.  The idea is that you run this script and it asks you some basic stuff about the site, and it sets up the folder structure and boilerplate.  You then could install dependencies (like jQuery), run your tests, and minify your code all through this tool.  The name sounds something like merlin, geany, or hoodini.  It wasn't really Google branded, and was an open source project.  I haven't heard anything about it since it was in its pre-release stages (hey check out this cool demo video), and I want to know what happened to it.  Did it ever get released?  Can I use this magical tool?

Does anyone remember what it's called?

Comment: Could be Google APP ENGINE, or http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service

Comment: Definitely not.  This wasn't really a Google branded project, it had it's own domain and no Google logo on the site.  I think the idea was that it would be maintained by an open source community in the long run, but it was in fact created by Google.

Comment: Dunno then soz :P

Comment: This question is about site management tool and nothing to do with html5. Are you asking something similar to Google Sites?

Comment: You can view a list of all current and discontinued Google projects on [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Google_Inc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeoman
http://yeoman.io/

After scrolling through the Google Chrome Developers Google Plus stream, I eventually saw the Yeoman image flash across my screen.  It looks like it's still being maintained and is as cool as it sounded.  I look forward to trying it out.

Comment: I thought about Yeoman too, as I vaguely remembered it being a Google product, but couldn't see anything linking them to google on the homepage. But if you go to their [github repo](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman#license), and scroll down to the bottom of the read me, you'll see that it's licensed to google.